# What is the ressource for make like PlayStore

Tags: android

I want to know what is the name for this :

- When we launch PlayStore for the first time, we have 3 page (who describe the app). After we have access to the Play Store and we never have again access to this.

I want to know what's is the name of this 3 "pages".

Screen : http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/google-play-update.png

Thank you

Comment: ViewPager is the most probably item.

Comment: Could you please upload one screenshot of what you are asking ?

Comment: I can't... I need reinitialize my phone for do it. When you launch for the first time Play Store, you have a screen who describe x, you have a button next, you have page y and again with page z. After this you have access to Play Store normaly, and when you launch again the app, you access normaly to the play store (i try to get a screen from google)

Comment: I've found a screen : http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/google-play-update.png

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems not to be about programming. It´s really unclear what you are asking. Please explain more detailed in an understandable way so we can help.

Comment: Screen 1 = Simple activity with ImageView. Screen 2 and Screen 3 = Two fragements in an activity.

Comment: @Jack : Thank you, so it's basic programming. But how they change de color of the statubar in a activity ?

Comment: @PotatoesPower use `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);` But this works in API 21 and above.